# Using Backbone.js do I need to use the form tag?

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js

My question is do I ever need to use the form tag?

If I were not using javascript I would use a form tag and it would submit itself. What I mean is that I didn't write any code on the client side.  Like so     (w3schools.com)

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" name="user">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Using Backbone.js I use the event: inside the view to catch the click on the submit button and then save the model.  Like so:

```
events: {
"click #submit": "SaveData",
},
SaveData: function(){
  /*javascript to save model or post using ajax */
}
```

Obviously I need the form tag in the first example but do I ever need it if I'm using ajax/javascript?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is do I ever need to use the form tag?

**No, you never need to use a form tag**. All backbone communication is via ajax.

Yes, as others have mentioned you **can optionally** construct your form tags, HTML, URLs, and server side code so they work correctly when used via regular form submission and full page loads.

I never use form tags, and here's why:

- I structure my backbone API URIs to match REST conventions, and my page URIs only sometimes correlate to those
- I think immediate autosave is a vastly superior interaction pattern, so when you check any checkbox, I send an AJAX PUT and your change is saved immediately without a submit button or full page load. Note that the default behavior of `Backbone.Model` is to send the entire record, which is not my personal preference, but I'm more of an RPC mindset vs REST.
- I probably don't want to code my server to work in both single-page fashion and multi-page fashion as doing so is vastly more difficult than the basic single-page style and not worth the effort unless you have extenuating circumstances requiring this.

  - a single page app just needs a basic index.html, a REST API that returns JSON exclusively, and a boatload of browser JS
  - if you want to be able to handle some or all of your operations via full page loads, you have a lot more server side coding to do to render server side HTML that exactly matches what your backbone browser code would do. You need something like [airbnb/rendr](https://github.com/airbnb/rendr), and it's non-trivial to put it lightly. Since your example indicates an ASP server, have fun sharing templates between ASP and backbone.
- if you don't include the `form` tags at all, you know you don't have to test them. If you include them, you are implying maybe they work, and then probably you should test them.
- if you don't include the `form` tags at all, it's one less unexpected set of HTTP requests to worry about on your server. It's clearer about your intent. It's an AJAX/JSON API. That's OK, embrace it.

On the whole "users with javascript disabled" thing - please stop saying this. Can anyone point to a single web application that uses backbone.js when JS is enabled AND can function with JS disabled? I don't think one has ever been written. Plus, it would feel like a time warp to a decade ago. If you are building a backbone app, you are whole-hog into JS. If you want your site to work without JS, don't use backbone, use a traditional multi-page web application framework.

Comment: You can avoid a lot of validation and event-binding headaches by using forms so that you can capture the `submit` separately of button `clicks`; that to me is worth it.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer. Using a form tag is useful if the `name` attributes of inputs correspond to backbone model properties. You can just serialize the form with a few little underscore.js functions and set the object to your model.

Comment: Yes, but DOM<->Model bindings like Knockback or similar are probably a better choice for that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to, but I think you **SHOULD** if it is a **FORM**.

Because it will be better to write semantic markup.

Here is an article talking about semantic html for your reference:
https://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/semantic-markup.html

Comment: Semantic markup on a javascript-heavy application is more of a novelty thing. I suppose it's still good practice to make co-worker's life easier, but isn't SEO supposed to be pretty terrible on a javascript heavy application? The markup probably won't even be crawled.

Comment: Didn't consider semantic aspects.  Perhaps I should but I've got my hands full enough already.  And backbone apps will be difficult to scan.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ps: I re-read your question and noticed it talks about a Backbone specific environment. I don't really know about Backbone, but the following should be applicable in general.

As most things in life, the answer is it depends.

Consider one scenario, if you press the `enter` key while the focus is on any input of the form, it will auto submit the form. If you click a button/input of type submit, it will submit the form. So you could potentially just listen for the form submit event, prevent the default action, and then fire your ajax query. If you already have a form in place, then you could use http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ to collect all the form fields for the ajax request.

For most part, I just let them be there. When reading the markup, the intent is clear. If the form has a `data-ajax="true"` then I know it's ajax enabled. From the `action` attribute of the form, I know the corresponding server url. I don't need to hunt down the corresponding js file to know where this form will be submitted to.